# Asp.net redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my page when edit button pressed it should go to edit page with filled form elements

```
if (e.CommandName == "edit")
  {
     dataaccess.Instance.get(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
     //code here
  }
```

How redirect to another page with a value(e.g id)

Comment: Just use `Response.Redirect` and pass `Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)` as URL-parameter which i assume is the ID. On the edit-page load the data from the database and fill the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("redirectpage.aspx?id="+e.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: how can i get that value on pageload method of next page

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the value from First page using Query String

```
Response.Redirect("thankyou.aspx?id="+e.CommandArgument);
```

And get the value in other page's page load method using

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
```

It's the easiest way to pass and get the variable between page but Query string is visible in Address bar chances of hacking or SQL Injection is more.

For that you can Encrypt the Query String before pass it in URL.

OR

You can use Session Variable too. which is more secure than Query String.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for this.